# How do I shift the x-axis over by one to start at 1 instead of 0?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

How do I start plotting my values at position 1 on the x-axis rather than 0? All the solutions I have seen for this have been pretty complex, I think I must be overlooking a simple way to specify this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_vals(vals, RANGE):
  plt.grid()
  plt.xticks(RANGE)
  plt.plot(vals, 'ro-')


RANGE = range(0, 11)

vals = [600.0, 222.3, 139.8, 114.0, 90.8, 80.8, 70.7, 62.8, 55.5, 47.5]
plot_vals(vals, RANGE)
```

yields this graph

[image]

All I want is x to run from 1 - 10 (instead 0 to 9) while keeping the all the values to be plotted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure this, you can pass a `range` for the `x` argument of `plt.plot` that runs from 1 to length of the values:

```py
plt.plot(range(1, len(vals) + 1), vals)
```

which gives this:

[image: plot1]

to see them in 1..10 fashion, we use `plt.xticks` with the same range:

```py
plt.xticks(range(1, len(vals) + 1))
```

to get

[image]

overall:

```py
x_range = range(1, len(vals) + 1)
plt.plot(x_range, vals)
plt.xticks(x_range)
```

(with the OOP style, last two lines' functions are `ax.plot` and `ax.set_xticks`)

Comment: Thank you, I esp like how you defined x_range once and reused it twice, my style (if I had know how to do it :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can do `plt.plot(RANGE, vals, 'ro-')` where the first argument is for x-axis, the second argument for y-axis. But then both `RANGE` and `vals` will have to be the same length, so you will need `RANGE = range(1, 11)`.

Answer (score 1):

This code works while making very few changes. The only two differences are calling RANGE into plt.plot and defining RANGE differently to avoid throwing an error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_vals(vals, RANGE):
  plt.grid()
  plt.xticks(RANGE)
  plt.plot(RANGE, vals, 'ro-')


RANGE = [i for i in range(1, 11)]

vals = [600.0, 222.3, 139.8, 114.0, 90.8, 80.8, 70.7, 62.8, 55.5, 47.5]
plot_vals(vals, RANGE)
```

[image: python code output example]

Here is a stripped down example that can be built upon as needed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [600.0, 222.3, 139.8, 114.0, 90.8, 80.8, 70.7, 62.8, 55.5, 47.5])
```

[image: python code output example]

Comment: Very nice, I thought I had tried this with `RANGE = list(range(1, 11))` but I didn't have it as a parameter in the plot function itself!